# How to get specific index of np.array of np.arrays fast

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

At the most basic I have the following dataframe:

```
a = {'possibility' : np.array([1,2,3])}
b = {'possibility' : np.array([4,5,6])}

df = pd.DataFrame([a,b])
```

This gives me a dataframe of size 2x1:
like so:

```
row 1:  np.array([1,2,3])
row 2:  np.array([4,5,6])
```

I have another vector of length 2.  Like so:

```
[1,2]
```

These represent the index I want from each row.
So if I have [1,2] I want: from row 1: 2, and from row 2: 6.
Ideally, my output is [2,6] in a vector form, of length 2.

Is this possible?  I can easily run through a for loop, but am looking for FAST approaches, ideally vectors approaches since it is already in pandas/numpy.

For actual use case approximations, I am looking to make this work in the 300k-400k row ranges. And need to run it in optimization problems (hence the fast part)

Comment: There's a separate array in each cell.  It isn't one multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform to a multi-dimensional numpy array and [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
v = np.array([1,2])
a = np.vstack(df['possibility'])
np.take_along_axis(a.T, v[None], axis=0)[0]
```

output: `array([2, 6])`

Comment: works! even when lengths are in the 3 million.  nice and sweet.  (though it does add 3 seconds to the calc...  are there simple optimizations from here?)

Comment: @user1639926 good question, I imagine most of the computing is spent stacking the arrays so I doubt you can greatly improve it. Might be worth asking a new `numpy` question though ;)